# How to manage sub-projects in Python?

Tags: python, git-submodules

I am developing a Python project, named `MyPkg`. I am contributing open-source to `ReqPkg`. Much of the functionality in `MyPkg` is dependent on capabilities of `ReqPkg`. I do not want to have to wait for major `ReqPkg` releases to PyPi for `MyPkg` to have newly developed functionality. I have setup `ReqPkg` as a git submodule. However, it is unclear to me if this is common practice in Python. Is there any way to maintain the integrity of `ReqPkg` as a standalone package and make it a sub-project like the structure shown below? Thanks.

```
MyPkg
├── MyPkg
│   ├── ReqPkg
│   │   ├── ReqPkg
│   │   │   └── module.py
│   │   └── setup.py
│   └── module.py
└── setup.py
```

Comment: typically if you're making changes to ReqPkg you'd submit them back to the main repository as a pull request and wait for a release.

Comment: @AdamSmith Yes the changes are being contributed to the main repo via pull requests, however what I really need is functionality in the main branch. Often things I contribute are because I need them right away.

Comment: You could work with the repo developers to start producing pre-release builds and specify those in your Python dependencies. You could alternatively develop your own module that you control that imports relevant parts of ReqPkg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip` is flexible, so if the package is on Github, you can fork the package and release it. Then you can install it from a release link:

```
pip install https://github.com/user/repo/archive/refs/tags/v4.0.1-dev.0.zip
```

Or if git is installed on your system and you are wanting to install up to a specific commit:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/user/repo.git@a6846sd1f65ds7f984g651sg687sd4f5d1af
```

Or if there is a specific branch that you want installed:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/user/repo.git@master
```